# How do I find the SQL behind an excel QueryTable

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to figure out what query is used to get some information in a spreadsheet.  When a button is clicked the VBScript code goes to this code:

```
With Sheet3
  .Visible = True
  .Select
  .Range("A1").Select
  Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  .Visible = False
End With
```

The only text in Sheet3 cell A1 is the text 
"O U T A G E   D A T A   F O R   D A I L Y   G R I D   S U M M A R Y"

I'm trying to figure out how they're getting the data (quite a large amount of it) from that QueryTable.  How can I find the actual query behind that QueryTable?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found:  I went to sheet 3 and then clicked the "Data" tab.  Everything in the "Get External Data" section was grayed out.  But if I clicked the drop down box below the Refresh All icon and click the "Connection Properties" link I get the Connection Properties dialog box.  In the definition tab of that dialog box there is the url of a web query.

And that's where the data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

According to [these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821552%28v=office.15%29.aspx), try `Selection.QueryTable.CommandText`.

Comment: I appreciate that.  If I try to look at ?Selection.QueryTable.CommandText in the Immediate Window I get no output and the value specifically says <Expression not defined in context>

Answer (score 0):

You can save the query as a text file (*.iqy) in the Query dialog's Save Query toolbar button.

This is a web query

```
WEB
1
https://www.google.com.au/

Selection=EntirePage
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```